# determine event path in DOM Event bubbling

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to find out the path through which an event has bubbled. For example , I have a mark up like

```
 <div id="container" onclick="func">
        <div id="div1"></div>
        <div id="div2">
            <div id="div2.1"></div>
            <span id="span2.2"></span>
            <div id="div2.3">
                <button id="btn2.3.1"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now if btn2.3.1 was clicked, I wish to see the entire path the event has bubbled up through which is btn2.3.1 -> div2.3 -> div2 ->container . Is there a way of doing this with only putting a handler on the container ? (No Jquery please)

I found a event.path array.Which does this stuff, but couldn't find much details about it.Is it cross browser? What is the correct way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

## `event.path || event.composedPath()`

#### `event.path`

Dis/Un-covered by a note in the [polymer project documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events.html#retargeting) and via [an HTML5Rocks article](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-301/#toc-events), `path` is a family tree in the form of an `Array`.

It appears to be an *"extension to the `event` interface"* only exposed via the [Web Component](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components) *Shadow DOM*, and is *standard* only in this respect (apparently), not a lot of documentation seems available, and it isn't exposed (by default) in all browsers.

### `event.composedPath()` to the rescue!

Another [question about the use of `path`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39245488/event-path-undefined-with-firefox-and-vue-js) was [answered with a suggestion to use `composedPath`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39245638/1832568)...

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org)'s [documentation about `event.composedPath()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/composedPath) describes it as follows:

> The `composedPath()` method of the [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) interface returns the event’s path which is an array of the objects on which listeners will be invoked. This does not include nodes in shadow trees if the shadow root was created with its [`ShadowRoot.mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot/mode) closed.

It is described by [WHATWG](https://whatwg.org/faq) in [their "DOM specs" documentation about the "event path"](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#event-path) as follows:

> Returns the [invocation target](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#event-path-invocation-target) objects of *event’s* path (objects on which listeners will be invoked), except for any [nodes](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-node) in [shadow trees](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-shadow-tree) of which the [shadow root](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-shadow-root)’s [mode](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#shadowroot-mode) is "closed" that are not reachable from event’s [currentTarget](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-event-currenttarget).

[Can I use...](https://caniuse.com/#info_about) states that [browser support of `composedPath()`](https://caniuse.com/#search=composedPath) is widespread, with all modern major browsers supporting its use, and [MDN agrees](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/composedPath#browser_compatibility).

[WHATWG's documentation about "dispatching events"](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dispatching-events) details the conditions under which "event's `path`" will have items [appended](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-event-path-append).

<sup>Details correct December 30, 2022</sup>

#### Practical demo

```js
const green = document.getElementById( 'green' ),
      msg = document.querySelector( 'output' );

document.getElementById( 'red' ).addEventListener( 'click', evt => {
  msg.innerHTML = '"' + evt.target.id + '" got poked, and "green" was' +
  
  /* access to the event path */
  ( ~evt.composedPath().indexOf( green ) ? '' : "<b>n't</b>" )
  
  + ' in the path.';
} );
```

```css
div { display: inline-block; padding: 1em 3em 1em 1em; cursor: pointer }
output { font-family: monospace; display: block; margin-top: 1em }
#red { background: red }
#green { background: green }
#blue { background: blue }
```

```html
<div id="red">
  <div id="green">
    <div id="blue"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<output>Poke the DOM!</output>
```

Comment: exactly this is the answer I was looking for

Comment: This works great in Chrome, but doesn't seem to be implemented in Firefox or IE yet? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @AdrianSchmidt Nope, you're not missing *something*. Bummer right? Yup.

Comment: @FredGandt To say the least... :(

Comment: I added a note about it. I suppose it's worth mentioning that it's not yet the be all and end all for this *problem*. Who knows though - next week it could be. We're on the bleeding edge! Dun dun duuuun! Alternatively it could be like another `font-stretch`. Wouldn't that be just spiffy? -_-

Comment: `event.path` is **not standard**. The `event path` in the quote is just like a local variable created when dispatching an event. But it's not exposed in the event.

Comment: @Oriol - It is standard, but apparently only to the Shadow DOM; it's there, but hidden. I have added notes to the answer. Although I haven't made any efforts to establish how, it should be possible to use `event.path` in any modern browser with a bit of jiggery-pokery.

Comment: @FredGandt I don't see `path` defined in the Shadow DOM draft neither. There is a [`deepPath`](https://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/shadow/#widl-Event-deepPath-sequence-EventTarget) method, but it does something different.

Comment: Moar links - https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=21066 via https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=234030 ... I dunno. As usual, Chrome is way ahead of the rest.

Comment: Love that `indexOf` where `~-1` returns false and everything else returns true!

Comment: @Qwerty more accurately; it's a bitwise NOT (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_NOT) that can be used in some cases like this as a shortcut/shorthand for a "truthy/falsy" statement. Since `~-1` resolves to `0` (falsy) and `~[any other possible return]` will resolve to a negative value (truthy), we can filter for hits. `!~array.indexOf` is also quite common.

Answer (score 23):

```
function handleClicks(e) {
    var path = [];
    var node = e.target;
    while(node != document.body) {
       path.push(node);
       node = node.parentNode;
    }
    console.log(path);
}

document.body.addEventListener('click', handleClicks);
```

Comment: So no other way other than looping ??

Comment: Yes, I think there is no other same perfomance and memory cost way

Comment: Some browsers (Chrome) now supports [event.path](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/dom3events/raw-file/tip/html/DOM3-Events.html#h-event-flow) property, which is event's propagation path `NodeList`.

Comment: What would be the best way to add this as a polyfill?

Comment: This solution won't work if the elements are not children of each other, but overlapping based on absolute positioning for example.

Comment: While not the list the op is requesting, be aware that `Element.closest()` polyfill exists and may help in other situations .. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar requirement where I was listening to event on document and wanted to know if the event originated in a particular div. I handled it by adding and later checking a specific class name on event.target.

```js
var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
var div2 = document.getElementById('div2');

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('via-div1')) {
    alert('Event came through div1');
  } else if (e.target.classList.contains('via-div2')) {
    alert('Event came through div2');
  } else {
    alert('Event came from outside the divs');
  }
});

div1.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.target.classList.add('via-div1');
});

div2.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.target.classList.add('via-div2');
});
```

```html
<div id="div1" style="background: #8bc34a"><span>div 1</span></div>
<div id="div2" style="background: #00bcd4">
  <span>div 2</span>
  <div id="div2-1"><span>div 2-1</span></div>
  <button id="btn2-2">button 2-2</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is now a small GitHub project / NPM module called `event-propagation-path` that acts as a polyfill. Check it out here:

[event-propagation-path @ GitHub](https://github.com/DieterHolvoet/event-propagation-path)

[event-propagation-path @ NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/event-propagation-path)

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that we what to find the event path inside the HTML table tag.

```
<tabe id="tab">
.
.
.
</table>
```

The following JavaScript code will return the event's element after every event.

```
window.onload = function(){
var tab = document.getElementById('tab');
tab.onclick = function(event) {
var target = getTargetElement(event);
console.log(target);
};
}
function getTargetElement(e) {
e = e || window.event;
return e.target || e.srcElement;
}
```