# br element with no parent node triggers paste event

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am having trouble getting the parent node of a `br` element which triggered a `ClipboardEvent`.

What I am trying to achieve is to recursively match its parent to a certain class, but the `br` element's `parentNode` property is `null`:

[image: br element]

Here is the DOM tree:

[image: br element in DOM tree]

The path property of the `ClipboardEvent` seems to capture the hierarchy but [it is not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26195091/determine-event-path-in-dom-event-bubbling):
[image: Event path]

Update:

I figured out why this is happening.

The `br` element was replaced by some new element upon pasting by the first event handler, and in my 2nd event handler(this one that I am having issue with), `br` is no longer in DOM tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `e.target.parentElement`

`e.target` will get the target of the event, in this case the `<br>`

**Demo**: https://codecanister.com/Project/d547eed9/6/result/

Comment: `e.target.parentElement` is `null` in this case, when `e.target` is `br`. See my first screenshot.

Comment: Totally works for me. Are you sure you are getting the correct `br`?

Comment: Try p > span > br,  without `input`

Comment: Uhm... That's strange. I will check again.

Comment: I think I figured out why this is happening. the `br` element was replaced by some new element upon pasting by the first event handler, and in my 2nd event handler(this one that I am having issue with), `br` is no longer in DOM tree.

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway.