# event.path is undefined running in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

When I run `event.path[n].id` in Firefox, I get this error. It works in other browsers.

> event.path undefined

Answer (score 180, accepted):

The `path` property of `Event` objects is non-standard. The standard equivalent is [the `composedPath` method](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-event-composedpath). But it was new when the question was asked (2016); it's well-established as of this update in January 2023.

So you may want to try `composedPath` and fall back to `path` (or just use `composedPath` now it's established):

```
// Written in ES5 for compatibility with browsers that weren't obsolete
// yet when the question was posted, although they are now
var path = event.composedPath ? event.composedPath() : event.path;
if (path) {
    // You got some path information
} else {
    // This browser doesn't supply path information
}
```

Obviously that won't give you path information if the browser doesn't supply it, but it allows for both the old way and the new, standard way, and so will do its best cross-browser.

Example:

```js
// Written in ES5 for compatibility with browsers that weren't obsolete
// yet when the question was posted, although they are now
document.getElementById("target").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    // Just for demonstration purposes
    if (e.path) {
        if (e.composedPath) {
            console.log("Supports `path` and `composedPath`");
        } else {
            console.log("Supports `path` but not `composedPath`");
        }
    } else if (e.composedPath) {
        console.log("Supports `composedPath` (but not `path`)");
    } else {
        console.log("Supports neither `path` nor `composedPath`");
    }

    // Per the above, get the path if we can, first using the standard
    // method if possible, falling back to non-standard `path`
    var path = event.composedPath ? event.composedPath() : event.path;

    // Show it if we got it
    if (path) {
        console.log("Path (" + path.length + ")");
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(path, function(entry) {
            console.log(entry === window ? "window" : entry.nodeName);
        });
    }
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="target">Click me</div>
```

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/composedPath), all major browsers support `composedPath` as of January 2023. Chrome (and other Chromium-based browsers) supported both `path` (it was a Chrome innovation) and `composedPath` until v109 when [`path` was removed](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5726124632965120). (The obsolete browsers IE11 and Legacy Edge [Microsoft Edge prior to v79 when it became a Chromium-based browser] didn't support either of them.)

If you ran into a browser that doesn't support either of them, I don't think you can get the path information as of when the event was triggered. You can get the path via `e.target.parentNode` and each subsequent `parentNode`, which is *usually* the same, but of course the point of `composedPath` is that it's not *always* the same (if something modifies the DOM after the event was triggered but before your handler got called).

Comment: Hey!
Thank you for your answer, but event.ComposedPath returned undefined in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: @Hanson: Right, again, it's the *new* standard for this. Chrome supports the old way (`path`). See the updated answer, I don't think this info is available on Firefox (or IE, didn't test Edge).

Comment: Yeah, FireFox definitely does not support this. :\

Comment: chiming in from 2018 - still no support in FF

Comment: @SMT: Indeed not, and surprisingly, I can't find a bugzilla entry for it. Just [this one](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1444857) from a month ago syncing up tests, and if you follow it to the [upstream bug](), Anne van Kesteren notes: "I suspect the reason this breaks the build is because Firefox doesn't implement these features." So who knows, maybe that will raise the profile.

Comment: It seems FF has support for `composedPath()` now (tested with version 59.0.3).

Comment: @PeterHerdenborg - Indeed! I've updated. Chrome does too now (it used to support only `path`). Also tested Edge, was sorry to see neither is supported.

Comment: The property 'composedPath' seems to be changed into 'composed', I guess to avoid a conflict between the property and the method. (Mac FF and Safari)

Comment: @Esger - No, `composed` is [something else entirely](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/composed), unrelated to `path` or `composedPath()`.

Comment: Is there any cost associated with accessing the eventPath in terms of performance? I am aware that DOM operations are expensive. Would this fall under those?

Comment: @NahushFarkande - DOM *mutations* can be expensive. This is just accessing DOM information, which may not be quite as cheap as accessing a JavaScript object property, but it'll be close. As always, worry about performance issues when you have a performance issue to worry about. :-)

Comment: Chrome has just removed `event.path` too (from 109) https://chromestatus.com/feature/5726124632965120

Answer (score 27):

You can create your own composedPath function if it's not implemented in the browser:

```
function composedPath (el) {

    var path = [];

    while (el) {

        path.push(el);

        if (el.tagName === 'HTML') {

            path.push(document);
            path.push(window);

            return path;
       }

       el = el.parentElement;
    }
}
```

The returned value is equivalent to event.path of Google Chrome.

Example:

```
document.getElementById('target').addEventListener('click', function(event) {

    var path = event.path || (event.composedPath && event.composedPath()) || composedPath(event.target);
});
```

Comment: That's is not actually the same, sometimes the parentElement is returning null is some cases and the event.path/composePath() will give you the full path..

Comment: This is **not** an implementation of `path`/`composedPath`. It misses the key aspect of them (which you can't polyfill).

Comment: The accepted answer misses this function to work on edge, since composed path is not supported either. Really nice.

Comment: this does not work in open shadow roots. I was looking for a Edge polyfill that would give me the source dom node within the web component, not the document.

Answer (score 12):

This function serves as a polyfill for `Event.composedPath()` or `Event.Path`

```
function eventPath(evt) {
    var path = (evt.composedPath && evt.composedPath()) || evt.path,
        target = evt.target;

    if (path != null) {
        // Safari doesn't include Window, but it should.
        return (path.indexOf(window) < 0) ? path.concat(window) : path;
    }

    if (target === window) {
        return [window];
    }

    function getParents(node, memo) {
        memo = memo || [];
        var parentNode = node.parentNode;

        if (!parentNode) {
            return memo;
        }
        else {
            return getParents(parentNode, memo.concat(parentNode));
        }
    }

    return [target].concat(getParents(target), window);
}
```

Comment: I've tested this approach and everything works like a charm!

Answer (score 5):

Use composePath() and use a polyfill for IE:
https://gist.github.com/rockinghelvetica/00b9f7b5c97a16d3de75ba99192ff05c

include above file or paste code:

```
// Event.composedPath
(function(e, d, w) {
  if(!e.composedPath) {
    e.composedPath = function() {
      if (this.path) {
        return this.path;
      } 
    var target = this.target;

    this.path = [];
    while (target.parentNode !== null) {
      this.path.push(target);
      target = target.parentNode;
    }
    this.path.push(d, w);
    return this.path;
    }
  }
})(Event.prototype, document, window);
```

and then use:

```
var path = event.path || (event.composedPath && event.composedPath());
```

Comment: This polyfill does not handle all cases. Especially when target is null. Consider the following scenario:
`const image = new Image(); image.onload = (e) => {
// Here event.target is null
console.log("path = ", e.composedPath()) // fire error
}`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I need the name of the HTML element. In Chrome I get the name with path. In Firefox I tried with *composedPath*, but it returns a different value.

For solving my problem, I used *e.target.nodeName*. With *target* function you can retrieve the HTML element in Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

This is my function in [Vue.js](http://%3Chttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vue.js%3E):

```
selectFile(e) {
        this.nodeNameClicked = e.target.nodeName
        if (this.nodeNameClicked === 'FORM' || this.nodeNameClicked === 'INPUT' || this.nodeNameClicked === 'SPAN') {
          this.$refs.singlefile.click()
      }
    }
```

Comment: A small improvement here - you can check for multiple values using an array:
```if (['FORM', 'INPUT', 'SPAN'].indexOf(this.nodeNameClicked) !== -1) {}```