# How to access element from this.event.path?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I basically want to access all the properties of an element that you get when say, that element is a target to an event. We do this via `this.event.target` to get access to all its properties.

What I want to do is search for `scrollTop` key of elements in the path of an event but all I am returned is their names instead of their equivalent JS objects.

Here's my try:

```
const viewport = this.event.path.filter(element => element.scrollTop) || { scrollTop: 0 };
```

But this just doesn't work and returns me an empty array.

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to do. Can you explain further?

Comment: Read the line of code.  Basically, I am trying to access the properties of the element but I am unable to do so.

Comment: As mentioned by youself, you can access the properties using `event.target`. So what is the problem?

Comment: Not the ones that you get from the event's path list!

Comment: You mean you want to get `.scrollTop` property of all elements in the event path?

Comment: Yes, my friend.

Comment: read this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39245488/event-path-undefined-with-firefox-and-vue-js/39245638#39245638 event.path is non standard

Comment: Set the event listener on `document` and then inspect `this.scrollTop` in the handler, not `this.target.scrollTop`.

Comment: @NathanSchwarz that's fine... I am really desperate to be able to access those elements for now

Comment: @ScottMarcus Don't want the scroll value of the document, but of another element.

Comment: Then simply test `this` before acting. It's pretty simple.

Comment: If you're setting an event listener on document @ScottMarcus, then something's very wrong.

Comment: @AakashVerma Uh no. You need to understand how event bubbling and [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) work. Setting event listeners on top level objects is very common and a very powerful way to write less code and increase page performance.

Answer (score 1):

you're not getting the scrollTop values because `filter` return the array containing all the elements having the properity scrollTop : do as following :

```
const viewport = this.event.composedPath().filter(element => element.scrollTop).map(e => { return e = {
//whatever you want to keep
scrollTop: e.scrollTop
}})
```

Here's a simple example to extract the scrollTop values from it with map

```js
document.querySelector('html').addEventListener('click',function(e) {
  let paths = e.composedPath().map(e => { return e.scrollTop || 0 })
  console.log(paths)
});
```

```css
div {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur pretium sed quam sed faucibus. Sed dictum enim non tortor egestas, sagittis mattis sem hendrerit. Duis quis massa turpis. Fusce consectetur facilisis lectus nec elementum. Praesent porttitor massa non enim bibendum, eu interdum lacus vehicula. Vestibulum efficitur felis sit amet ipsum venenatis interdum. Sed vulputate nibh id mi egestas, eu rutrum tellus dignissim. Sed suscipit risus condimentum libero pulvinar venenatis. Maecenas semper, erat eget dictum egestas, nisl urna finibus quam, a fermentum magna ante vel erat. Integer sed neque tristique, bibendum nisl et, pretium augue. Duis malesuada odio vitae commodo venenatis. Nunc consequat libero ac velit tempus sollicitudin. Sed scelerisque velit sem, ac pellentesque tellus rutrum eget. Aliquam convallis, ipsum id consectetur tempor, nibh odio fermentum orci, vitae imperdiet felis arcu vel elit. Sed venenatis et erat eget scelerisque. Aliquam consectetur nibh eu augue dignissim, a vestibulum ligula facilisis.

Quisque tincidunt in nulla ut placerat. Nullam posuere massa et urna eleifend consectetur. Praesent in odio mauris. Quisque pellentesque ante vitae justo consequat, vel posuere sapien lacinia. Aliquam varius diam nec purus scelerisque lobortis. Donec nisi mi, imperdiet posuere orci in, lobortis egestas purus. Aenean luctus egestas eleifend. Donec semper lectus nunc, eget consectetur nulla commodo vel. Aliquam erat volutpat. Quisque sodales enim sed diam pretium, eget finibus felis interdum. Mauris mattis id velit quis tincidunt. Fusce et pellentesque felis. Proin fermentum, est sed malesuada egestas, lorem nisl luctus mi, non tempor mi leo id nunc. In viverra rhoncus pulvinar. Duis dictum sem ac nisi fermentum, non iaculis eros convallis.

Vestibulum pharetra neque vitae auctor fermentum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi eu erat sed ante cursus congue quis nec metus. Donec et erat sed quam faucibus pellentesque. Donec eu orci id justo dignissim tempor at sit amet dui. Curabitur varius lobortis pellentesque. Duis et diam sed ligula laoreet maximus in vel ex. Sed consequat eleifend libero a accumsan. Maecenas convallis tellus lobortis tristique vulputate. Morbi luctus a nisl ac accumsan. Integer dignissim orci et rhoncus porta.

Curabitur lacinia ullamcorper turpis in tincidunt. Nulla facilisi. Sed blandit ultricies arcu, vitae luctus nisi suscipit non. Fusce iaculis dapibus risus. Praesent turpis purus, sodales eget condimentum nec, vehicula id erat. Cras placerat velit justo, non imperdiet quam efficitur in. Fusce sit amet nisl sed purus vestibulum interdum. In felis mi, finibus non sagittis ut, accumsan a velit.

Nunc et ullamcorper mi. Donec vulputate tortor ante, in consequat enim facilisis condimentum. Nullam fermentum, libero ac iaculis tincidunt, dui nibh varius enim, in sollicitudin elit arcu eget libero. Quisque tincidunt mauris ex, sed congue augue faucibus at. Phasellus accumsan urna id enim ullamcorper suscipit. Pellentesque id quam a enim hendrerit dictum. Etiam sit amet dapibus justo, at sollicitudin urna. Etiam sodales efficitur urna, tempor ullamcorper tellus blandit sit amet. Ut magna magna, euismod et viverra suscipit, tristique posuere enim. Phasellus augue ex, viverra a pretium vel, porttitor a turpis. In placerat lectus eu suscipit sodales. Nam at placerat odio. Vivamus ullamcorper fringilla quam in iaculis. Maecenas id viverra nibh. Nunc lorem nunc, auctor non augue a, aliquam dictum lorem. Phasellus pretium nibh in nunc fermentum scelerisque et vel turpis.
  </span>
</div>
```

scroll the text and click on it

Comment: Please do not post code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time and then your answer here becomes meaningless. Just create a code snippet in your answer.