# Firefox - Event Path is undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

My code works perfectly in Google Chrome, but with firefox it get's this error:

> TypeError: e.path is undefined

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
if (e.path[2].id == 'v-pills-rest-tab') {
    if (e.path[2].getAttribute("aria-selected") == "true") {
        document.getElementById('rect').style.fill = '#F15A29';
        document.getElementById('v-pills-profile-tab').style.color = '#F15A29';
    }
} else {
    if (document.getElementById('v-pills-rest-tab').getAttribute("aria-selected") == "false") {
        document.getElementById('rect').style.fill = '#C4C4C4';
        document.getElementById('v-pills-profile-tab').style.color = '#414042';
    }
}
    if (document.getElementById("pills-profile-tab").getAttribute("aria-selected") != "true" && document.getElementById("pills-contact-tab").getAttribute("aria-selected") != "true" ) {
            document.getElementById("mob-num-wrapper").style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

Comment: Duplicated question. Please search similar questions before asking. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39245488/event-path-undefined-with-firefox-and-vue-js

Comment: sorry i saw this answer but i failed to make it work

Comment: sorry i saw this answer but i failed to make it work

Comment: If that is the case, you should have added it in your question. That shows the research whatever you have done. Moreover the accepted answer is no way different than the answer given in the dupe.,

Comment: I understood. Now everything succeeded and I marked the correct answer.