# Get event target inside a web component

Tags: javascript, dom, events, web-component, shadow-dom

Anchor elements (`<a>`) are created when the user interacts with a web component. The problem is, that I cannot get the anchor element returned from the "outside" of the web component when an anchor is clicked.

I add an event listener to `document` listening for click events. When an element somewhere in the DOM is clicked I expect the `e.target` to be the clicked element.
In the case of a click somewhere inside the web component the custom element (`<fancy-list></fancy-list>`) will be returned - not the clicked element.

When the mode of the shadow DOM is set to `open` the DOM should be accessible.

```js
class Fancylist extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });

    const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    wrapper.innerHTML = `<ul></ul><button>Add item</button>`;

    shadow.appendChild(wrapper);

    this.on_root_click = this.on_root_click.bind(this);
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.ul_elm = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('ul');
    this.shadowRoot.addEventListener('click', this.on_root_click, false);
  }

  on_root_click(e){
    switch(e.target.nodeName){
      case 'BUTTON':
        this.ul_elm.innerHTML += '<li><a href="p1">List item</a></li>';
        break;
      case 'A':
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('You clicked a link!');
        break;
    }
  }
}

customElements.define('fancy-list', Fancylist);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>List</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
        document.body.addEventListener('click', e => {
          //console.log(e.composedPath());
          console.log(e.target); // why is this not returning an anchor element when an anchor is clickend inside the <fancy-list>?
        }, false);
      }, false);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>List</h1>
  <fancy-list></fancy-list>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The purpose of the *Shadow* DOM is precisely *to mask* the HTML content the Shadow DOM from the containter point of view.

That's also why inner events are retargeted in order to expose the Shadow DOM host.

However, you can still get the real target by getting the first item of the `Event.path` Array property.

```
event.path[0]
```

NB: of course it will work only with `open` Shadow DOM.

```js
class Fancylist extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });

    const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    wrapper.innerHTML = `<ul></ul><button>Add item</button>`;

    shadow.appendChild(wrapper);

    this.on_root_click = this.on_root_click.bind(this);
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.ul_elm = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('ul');
    this.shadowRoot.addEventListener('click', this.on_root_click, false);
  }

  on_root_click(e){
    switch(e.target.nodeName){
      case 'BUTTON':
        this.ul_elm.innerHTML += '<li><a href="p1">List item</a></li>';
        break;
      case 'A':
        e.preventDefault();
        break;
    }
  }
}

customElements.define('fancy-list', Fancylist);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>List</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
        document.body.addEventListener('click', e => {
          console.log(e.path[0]);
        }, false);
      }, false);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>List</h1>
  <fancy-list></fancy-list>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Update 2021**

As commented now you should use `event.composedPath()`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It does not work in Firefox and it made me search for more answers -- I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39245638/322084 apparently we have different implementations of that functionality, Event.path and Event.composedPath().

Comment: Use `event.composedPath()` instead of `event.path`

Comment: Regrettably, the event `:target` is missing in the shadow root of the web components. There are no sign that any of the browsers will fix this so far. I wonder if they are waiting for the W3C to do something or some other standard entity.

Answer (score 2):

- Firefox: `event.originalTarget` or `event.explicitOriginalTarget`, Non-standard, Do not use it on production!
- DOM Standard: `event.composedPath()[0]`

more info

- [Event: originalTarget property - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/originalTarget)
- [Event: composedPath() method - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/composedPath)
- [Bubbling, event.composedPath() - The Modern JavaScript Tutorial](https://javascript.info/shadow-dom-events#bubbling-event-composedpath)