# How to detect events on child elements of custom element?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, web-component, custom-element

I'm trying to write a script that detects clicks on a button for a page the HTML of which I do not control.

However, if I add an event listener on the document, the target of the event object is an element named "c-sto_com_fs-content-page", and not my "a.btn-primary" button. In Firefox the proprietary originalTarget property does show me the right element, but that's not a great help.
The "c-sto_com_fs-content-page" element is located about halfway between my button and the document body.
This page's HTML is a bit of a mess.

I figured I could simply querySelector my way to the button, and hook up an event listener that way, but document.querySelector("c-sto_com_fs-content-page a.btn-primary") also returns null.
document.querySelector("c-sto_com_fs-content-page") returns the custom element, but I can't use this node to navigate down. It's as if this node's children do not exist.

How do I get this working?

Comment: Did you forget the dot (`.`) at the beginning of your class selector?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl: if only. The element is really `<c-sto_com_fs-content-page data-data-rendering-service-uid="34" data-aura-rendered-by="163:0">`

Answer (score 0):

The element `<c-sto_com_fs-content-page></c-sto_com_fs-content-page>`, is a web component on the page. The `.target` property of the `Event` object will always be the web component. Use the `Event.composedPath()` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/composedPath) to get to an element within the web component in the document's click handler.

```
document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    console.log(e.target); // Always returns <c-sto_com_fs-content-page>
    console.log(e.composed);
    console.log(e.composedPath());
});
```

The web component is in open mode or closed mode. See this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39931284/what-is-the-difference-between-open-and-closed-shadow-dom-encapsulation-mode). If it's in open mode then the following should return the element within the web component that's the target of the click event.

```
console.log(e.composedPath()[0]);
```

Inspecting the HTML in the browser's console will show if the web component is in open or closed mode:

```
<c-sto_com_fs-content-page>
    #shadow-root (open)
    <a class="btn-primary">Ok</a>
</c-sto_com_fs-content-page>
```

As per the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/composedPath#examples) article,

> ...the event listeners only propagate as far as the  element itself, but not to the nodes inside the shadow boundary.

Here's an older [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57963312/get-event-target-inside-a-web-component) on the topic of getting the event target within a web component.

Comment: As I said in the question: the target property is not set to the clicked element, but to an ancestor element c-sto_com_fs-content-page.