# Alternative to composedPath for Edge

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I would like to be able to detect the path when I click somewhere using Edge/IE. With [all other browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=composedPath) I can use [event.composedPath()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/composedPath), but Edge and IE don't support it.

I've been looking around and I only [found pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39245488/event-path-undefined-with-firefox-and-vue-js) discouraging from using `path` and using `composedPath()` instead, but I didn't find any reference for Edge.

Help, please!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to check this polyfill may help to get composed path.

```
// Event.composedPath
(function(e, d, w) {
  if(!e.composedPath) {
    e.composedPath = function() {
      if (this.path) {
        return this.path;
      } 
    var target = this.target;

    this.path = [];
    while (target.parentNode !== null) {
      this.path.push(target);
      target = target.parentNode;
    }
    this.path.push(d, w);
    return this.path;
    }
  }
})(Event.prototype, document, window);
```

use it like below:

```
var path = event.path || (event.composedPath && event.composedPath());
```

References:

(1) [event.path undefined with Firefox and Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39245488/event-path-undefined-with-firefox-and-vue-js)

(2) [rockinghelvetica/composedpath.polyfill.js](https://gist.github.com/rockinghelvetica/00b9f7b5c97a16d3de75ba99192ff05c)

Other than that I did not got any alternative or work around to get Event.Composedpath for IE and Edge browsers.