# Auto-save all inputs value to localStorage and restore them on page reload

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm about to code, in Javascript some code (involving looping on each `<input>` and adding listeners):

- allowing, after keypress, to save all `<input>` values to `localStorage`
- restore all `<input>` values from `localStorage` in the case the page/browser has been closed and reopened on the same page

**But maybe is there an automatic way, provided by the browsers?**

e.g. by adding an attribute to `<input>`, similar to `<input autofocus>` (which is not related here)

Question: is there an autosave feature of `<form>` `<input>` HTML tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no built-in way to do that, you should do it manually;

```js
function persist(thisArg) {
  localStorage.setItem(thisArg.id, thisArg.value);
}
```

```html
<input id="test" onchange="persist(this)" />
```

---

persist and retrieve all together:

```js
function persist(event) {
  localStorage.setItem(event.target.id, event.target.value);
}

// you may use a more specific selector;
document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach((inputEl) => {
  inputEl.value = localStorage.getItem(inputEl.id);
  inputEl.addEventListener("change", persist);
});
```

```html
<input id="test" />
```

Comment: Thank you. For future reference, could you also include the code to restore the values from localStorage after a page reload?

Comment: PS @Leonardo `event.path[0]` does not work for Firefox, I think `event.target` is better or maybe use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39245488/event-path-is-undefined-running-in-firefox/39245638#39245638? What do you think?

Comment: @Basj `event.target` is more appropriate then; I didn't know `event.path` isn't implemented in firefox; I'd updated the answer accordingly

Comment: In your second example, you could put a single listener on `document` instead to save data, and you could update your selector to `input[id]` to ensure all saved elements have IDs (in order to save them by that)... otherwise, you're right!

Comment: @FZs Not sure to see exactly what you mean, could you post an answer with this? It's always interesting to see slightly many solutions :)

Comment: @Basj FZs points out that if some input don't have `id` then `event.target.id` in `.setItem(event.target.id,...` will be undefined and woudn't have correct reference as `key`; so he suggests to use `id` in `document.querySelectorAll` to ensure all element have correct `key` value in localstorage

Answer (score 2):

there is no automatic way to do that.
you have two options :

1. save the data by code 

   example:

```
localStorage.setItem('testObject', JSON.stringify(yourObject)); // for storing data
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('yourObject')); // for retrieving data
```

code snippet:

```js
// for saving data

function saveData(el) {
  localStorage.setItem(el.id, JSON.stringify(el.value));
}

// for retrieving data on page load

function getData() {
  var inp = document.getElementById("inp");
  inp.value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('inp')) || "";
}
```

```html
<body onload="getData()">
    <input id="inp" onchange="saveData(this)" />
</body>
```

2. try a helper library like [persisto](https://github.com/mar10/persisto)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the accepted answer, here is a one-liner that can be useful:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input:not([type="submit"])').forEach(elt => { elt.value = localStorage.getItem(elt.name); elt.addEventListener("change", e => { localStorage.setItem(e.target.name, e.target.value); }); });
```

It serializes/deserializes the `<input>`s to `localStorage`, indexed by their attributes `name`.