# How to use e.path in addEventListener cross-browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, addeventlistener

This works on Chrome:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]').forEach(elt => { 
    elt.addEventListener("change", e => { 
        localStorage.setItem(e.path[0].name, e.path[0].value); 
    });
});
```

but generates this on Firefox:

> TypeError: e.path is undefined

**What is a cross-browser equivalent of `e.path[0]`?**

Comment: what type of element is that?

Comment: @DanielA.White I edited to add more precision: it's an `<input type="text">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firefox equivalent is** `e.composedPath()`

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]').forEach(elt => { 
    elt.addEventListener("change", e => { 
        let path = e.path || e.composedPath()
        localStorage.setItem(path[0]?.name, path[0]?.value); 
    });
});
```

If both of them are not supported in the browser still it wont give an error but set Item undefined:undefined because of the usage **path?.property**

Comment: What cross-browser solution would you use (working for Firefox, Chrome, IE, etc.)?

Comment: This seems to solve it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39245488/event-path-is-undefined-running-in-firefox/39245638#39245638 : `var path = event.path || (event.composedPath && event.composedPath());
`

Comment: PS: what about simply `e.target`?

Comment: if you only want path[0] then e.target would be correct