# How to get DOM List when mouseover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, dom

The `DOM List` means the DOM sequence. Such as below image.

[image]

But this only shows in Chrome. I can't get path in Firefox, And I have searched a lot of material, someone provide below code to compatible.

```
let path = event.path || (event.composedPath && event.composedPath());
```

But it didn't work. So, any suggestion?

```
$('body')
  .children()
  .mouseover(event => {
    let path = event.path || (event.composedPath && event.composedPath());
    console.log(path); // undefined
  });
```

Firefox version: 78.0.2 (64-bit)

Comment: Works here - Firefox 76.0b6 (64-bit). You must be checking in version lower than 52

Comment: I found answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39245488/event-path-is-undefined-running-in-firefox

Comment: Which one worked for you?

Comment: let target = event.target;
      while (target.parentNode) {
        target = target.parentNode;
        console.log(target);
      }