# Read dataset from parent of clicked element

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have the following html and Javascript. I want to have a set of buttons with a single `onclick` handler.

```
    <div id="parent1">
        <button data-idx="1" data-action="test">Click me</button>
        <button data-idx="2" data-action="test">Click me</button>
    </div>
    <div id="parent2">
        <button data-idx="1" data-action="test"><span>Click me</span></button>
        <button data-idx="2" data-action="test"><span>Click me</span></button>
    </div>
    <script>
        const parent1 = document.querySelector("#parent1");
        const parent2 = document.querySelector("#parent2");
        parent1.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
            let obj = evt.target.dataset;
            console.log(obj);
        });
        parent2.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
            let obj = evt.path[1].dataset;
            console.log(obj);
        });
    </script>
```

The code for `parent1` works fine and I see `{idx:"1", action:"test"}`

The code for `parent2` works as well, *but only* because in this example I know in advance the structure of the `innerHtml` of the buttons. In practise that is **not** known, and the hard-coded `evt.path[1]` is not suitable.

It is the case however that the dataset is always in the immediate child of `#parent2`

How can I reliably find the dataset? For example, can I get the index relative to `#parent` of the child that fired the event?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use composedpath instead of path: see [event.path is undefined running in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39245488/event-path-is-undefined-running-in-firefox).

In generall you can loop over the path[n] and avoid undefined errors.

Or you can access the different variables by using your above `evt.target.dataset[keyname]`.