# "get ElementById" not working on firefox?

Tags: javascript, html

I can get the file name from file upload to the textarea in IE and Chrome.
But it not work on firefox, how can i solve this problem?

Many Thanks.

```js
        function takeName(event) {
            let filename = event.path[0].files[0].name;
            document.getElementById("txtComment").value = filename;
        }
```

```html
<form id="Apply" name="Apply" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="applyLeave.php">
    Get upload filename to textarea:
    <p><textarea rows="3" cols="30" name="txtComment" id="txtComment" class="valid"></textarea></p>
    <p>Select image to upload: <input type="file" onchange="takeName(event)" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: What's the problem? How do you know it doesn't work on Firefox?

Comment: Well I use Firefox and `document.getElementById` posted works just fine.

Comment: Your code conflates multiple possibilities, so step 1 is to split it up. `let element = event.path[0]; let file = element.files[0]; let name = file.name; let comment = document.getElementById("txtComment"); comment.value = filename;` and then you'll first notice that you wanted `event.target`, not `event.path[0]` and then you'll notice this had nothing to do with `document.getElementById` and you jumped to conclusions rather than verifying your assumptions. Always good to get extra verbose when you're debugging. You can always collapse it again once things work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementById()` compatibility with any browser is unquestionable that isn't the problem. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39245638/2813224) about `.path` compatibility with Firefox.

Replace `event.path[0]` with [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).

```js
function takeName(event) {
  let filename = event.target.files[0].name;
  document.getElementById("txtComment").value = filename;
}
```

```html
<form id="Apply" name="Apply" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="applyLeave.php">
  Get upload filename to textarea:
  <p><textarea rows="3" cols="30" name="txtComment" id="txtComment" class="valid"></textarea></p>
  <p>Select image to upload: <input type="file" onchange="takeName(event)" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"></p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

When I use in firefox that show `event.path is undefined`, I suggest you use `event.target.files` to get file name