# How to iterate the DOM to rebuild data structure and find relevant element

Tags: javascript, html

I want to lookup some data inside a tag, I do not know if the tag would be a `<div>` or a `<p>` or a `<span>` or any other text element tag. Other than reading the data, I want to record where the relevant tag is to be found inside a page. Here is an example:

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <p>irrilevant data</p>
    <p>Interesting data</p>
</div>
```

When the user right click the relevan data of interest, I need to record the relevant data as also where this data is in the DOM considering the first parent, for example I wrote this and it is working fine:

```
<script>
    // Function to handle global right-click
    function handleGlobalRightClick(event) {
        // Get the clicked element
        let clickedElement = event.target;

    if (!clickedElement.id){
       //the element has no id i need to find the nth 
           let clickedElementParent = event.target.parentElement;
           // Traverse up the DOM hierarchy to find the first element with an id
       while (!clickedElementParent.id) {
          clickedElementParent = clickedElementParent.parentElement;
           }

           // If the clicked element has a parent and it has multiple children, find the index
           let childIndex = null;
           if (clickedElementParent && clickedElementParent.children.length > 1) {
               const childNodes = clickedElementParent.children;
               for (let i = 0; i < childNodes.length; i++) {
                   if (childNodes[i] === clickedElement) {
                       childIndex = i;
                       break;
                   }
               }

            // Log or use the id and index of the clicked element
            console.log(`Parent Id: ${clickedElementParent.id}`);
            console.log(`Child Index: ${childIndex}`);

           }

    } else {
        //the element has an id, problem solved
    }

    }

</script>
```

All fun and games until the structure is a little more complicated, for example consider the following page content:

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <p>Right-click me</p>
    <div>
       <p>Interesting data</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this case, the code above will not work and return *null* in this case i'd need to record the `myDiv` as first parent with an ID and the nodes to reach my wanted *interesting data* in short a way to pin-point where the data is to be found inside the page. Perhaps my approach is wrong or more complicated than it could be. Imagine I could have an even more intricated content page, with more nested nodes and such.

My next move would be to write an iterator and note down every `childIndex` in progression until I reach the *relevant data* but maybe this would not be the correct approach or is there a better, more readable way to write this script?

Comment: it would be relevant to know how did you attach that function to the right click event. You called it `handleGlobalRightClick` but it's not clear if it's listening to `document` or any element in the page. And also you said it returns null but not following which event (when you clicked on the div itself? on the children? how delegation is handled?)

Comment: *"and the nodes to reach my wanted interesting data"*: please provide the concrete result you want for the example.

Comment: @trincot any form that can be used to express a path, the answers are pointing in the right direction so far, I need to test them.

Comment: @DiegoD `document` actually but omitted in case someone find a smarter way, less intensive on RAM or processor, probably listening the whole document is not the best choice.

Answer (score 2):

While you traverse up the hierarchy to find the element with the `id` property (which your code does successfully), also track the child index *at each step*. This series of indexes can then be used to indicate the path from the id-node to the clicked node.

Like this (I didn't bother checking whether the click is a right click):

```js
function handleGlobalRightClick(event) {
    // Get the clicked element
    let elem = event.target;
    // The path downwards from an element with an id towards the clicked element
    const path = [];

    while (elem.parentElement && !elem.id) {
        path.push([].indexOf.call(elem.parentElement.children, elem));
        elem = elem.parentElement;
    }
    path.reverse();
    console.log(`Parent Id: ${elem.id}`);
    console.log(`Child Index/path: ${path.join(" ")}`);
}

document.addEventListener("click", handleGlobalRightClick);
```

```css
div { border: 1px solid; margin: 10px }
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
    <p>If you click here the path is "0" (first child)</p>
    <div>
       <p>if you click here, the path is "1 0"</p>
       <div>
           <p>if you click here, the path is "1 1 0"</p>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div>
       <p>if you click here, the path is "2 0"</p>
       <div>
           <p>if you click here, the path is "2 1 0"</p>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: tested this on a sample pga with lot of nodes and it returns this: `Child Index/path: 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0` the parent Id is correct. The same file using a diffrent approach returns: `Path: 1 0 2 0 0 1 0 0` and i can confirm the latter is the correct of the two.

Comment: Can you provide the HTML structure where you get this difference? Of course, it would be better if you could find a *minimal* example where you believe you get the wrong result.

Comment: Here is a sample: https://pastebin.com/vELz1wkD the sample continues below, that's why it detects the 2 as first node on your test, I omitted this part since the first 2 is already wrong, the data is inside the 2nd node with index 1 as in path.

Comment: I could not open that link. I don't understand what you are trying to explain here.

Answer (score 1):

The `event.path` property contains an array representing the DOM hierarchy from the target element, up to the root of the document.

```js
function handleGlobalRightClick(event) {
    // Get the clicked element
    let clickedElement = event.target;

    // Find the first parent element with an id
    let parentWithId = event.composedPath().find(element => element.id);

    if (parentWithId) {
        console.log(`Parent Id: ${parentWithId.id}`);

        // Find the index of the clicked element within its parent
        let childIndex = Array.from(clickedElement.parentElement.children).indexOf(clickedElement);
        console.log(`Child Index: ${childIndex}`);
    }
}
```

Comment: you probably meant to use [composedPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/composedPath) since `path` was removed [further info on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39245488/event-path-is-undefined-running-in-firefox)

Comment: @DiegoD would this work both in Firefox and Chrome?

Comment: confirmed `event.path is undefined` error, this is not working. Tried with `composedPath` and got a `Uncaught TypeError: event.composedPath.find is not a function` error instead.

Comment: Yup, sorry, `path` was removed, but on some browsers its still working. `composedPath()`, is working for me. Edited the answer :).

Comment: Can you test the sameple https://pastebin.com/vELz1wkD with your method? I keep getting the error on `composedPath` on Firefox.