# Why does click event on window not have target event path unless within setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am working on a JavaScript library for some data collection. I need to capture all click events, and want to traverse the event path looking for specific tags/ids/classes on click.

If I run the following code without the setTimeout, the event path always comes back with a single object in the array for `Window`. Add the setTimeout and the event path comes as expected.

```
window.addEventListener('click', function (event) {    
    // setTimeout with a 4ms delay to push to the end of the JS execution queue.
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(event.path);
    }, 4);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for window to load, use below code so you should get the same result without the time delay:

```
window.onload = function() {
   document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {    
       console.log(event.path);
   });
};
```

Comment: The window.onload event has already fired in my case, and this has no effect on my example.

Comment: This answer looks like it might be right for the wrong reason.  loading is probably not an issue.  I can replicate the problem in my javascript console on chrome using OP's code, but if I instead add the event listener to the document (not window) it works.  I can't find documentation on `event.path`, but the solution might be to add the listener to the document object.

Comment: @JosephMarikle Interesting. I am seeing the same result. If I put the event listener on the `document`, or `document.body`, the full path is populated without having to have the `setTimeout`. I still would love to have a better understanding why the path isn't populated when the listener is on the `window`

Comment: @JeremyH. You and me both.  Do you have some documentation on this property?  The closest I can find is [`deepPath`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/deepPath).

Comment: @JosephMarikle This [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30021867/1440000) or [here](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#event-path).