# How to get the contenteditable target of a keyup event caught by a parent element in shadow root?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, event-handling, dom-events, keyevent

I created a shadow root in the content script of a Chrome extension, and in the shadow root I created a container with id 'container' containing three elements, namely 'parent-1', 'parent-2', and 'parent-3'. In each parent element, there is a child element with contenteditable as true: 'child-1', 'child-2', 'child-3' correspondingly.

```
<div id="container" onkeyup="catchEventsFun">
  <div id="parent-1">
    <div contenteditable id="child-1"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="parent-2">
    <div contenteditable id="child-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="parent-3">
    <div contenteditable id="child-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when 'child-2' element is triggered by 'keyup' event, the event.target caught in catchEventsFun is the shadow root element.

Methods I've tried:

1. use the [composedPath or path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30021867/3552975): failed with path as null, composedPath as [], and event.composed as true
2. use event.currentTarget: failed with currentTarget as null

How can I get the 'child-2' element as its event bubbles up to the shadow root?

Comment: It works correctly when I use event.target but not when I expand `event` in devtools console afterwards. It's because `target` is adjusted for each event listener while the event bubbles up and ends at the root.

Comment: I console.log the event.target.id, and I didn't see the 'child-2'. @wOxxOm

Comment: @wOxxOm It's funny that it works correctly as you said in popup.js.